# Locked post apply for unlock

Tags: support, status-declined

This is the [post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/270373/csgo-mm-official-servers-periodically-high-delay) I am talking about, so Fredley now give me a VERY good explantion why you closed my post.

Just to know if it is because of the "greetings message" then show me the RULE that says that I am not allowed to greed the community on my post or open the post asap...

Comment: Since You Asked: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/165776

Comment: Generally, being hostile isn't going to help you.

Comment: @KutuluMike  think again before answering... i said RULE!!! not simple guideline/proposal/opinion of someone which as long as it is not a RULE i do not care about... tnx

Comment: @Frank dont care... simple...

Comment: Okay. So go have fun, then. We don't allow it, you ignored us, this is what happens.

Comment: @Frank hahahhahhahahha ok then... one question though... who THE HELL ARE YOU!!!! that you will tell ME that YOU wont allow this!!!!!

Comment: @KutuluMike still waiting for the rule that specifficaly says that an OP is NOT allowed to greed the community on his post.... i dont want to hear anything else except that one... follow the guidelines...

Comment: Please read [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11177/this-site-should-be-called-minimodding-com/). Especially the answers.

Comment: @ardaozkal your and his words have no value if they dont stand on a point and on facts.... bring me facts and if they are correct i will accept them, the rest is just words on the air..

Comment: [Here's some relevant reading.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-great-edit-wars/) It boils down to: 1. Stop changing solid edits back to your original version.  2. Be nice.  3. Stop changing the OP's version if he is super resistant to the change, because we'd rather be nice than have a perfect looking question.  4. Mods lock posts when these things keep changing back and forth to give it time to cool down.  #4 is what happened. Everyone else can argue about #1 and #3 to decide the final form the question ends up in.

Comment: @Sterno if you would actually read the rollbacks you would actually see that even if i rollbacked couple of time i kept what I THOUGHT it was making the question better..... I didnt because of ego roll back the question, i just took out of the edits what I thought it wasnt a "better" change...

Comment: @hedgehog I'm making no judgments either way. I didn't bother to read the rollbacks. I was trying to answer your question about why it got locked. It got locked because an edit war was happening.

Comment: @Sterno you are not making judgements?????Look at your 1st point....... None has a point here actually, i am counter arguing everything so easily..... I will start thinking that this is more a bully community than a helpful one...

Comment: Congratulations on completely dismantling an argument I wasn't making, I guess?

Answer (score 11):

Your question was locked because you kept reverting every attempt to improve it. When people edit your question or answer, they are trying to help it be better or more concise. It's not a good idea to just revert edits unless you can make a good argument that the edit damages the post in question.

Comment: Am I the OP? Do i own the question? Then i can judge what is helpfull for MY question and what is not.. If i say i want that thing on the top, then I will have that thing on the top.... The edit is a suggestion of someone and a try to help me improve my question, as the OP i always hold the ability to accept that change or not... If you would think a bit before posting this answer then you would have seen that my question as it is now from the original one is not the same, it has changes, the ones i AGREED on.....

Comment: I have a very simple answer for what you are saying.... After I create a post and after someone edits my question, does the system give me the ability to roll back and make my own changes without asking none? To save you the time the answer is yes.... Something else to maybe prove a point here?

Comment: @hedgehog StackExchange is a community-edited site, however; you don't own the *exclusive right* to control the content you post here, and that means you don't have the final say over an edit. Just as other users do not have that final say either (see [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/editing)). Except, of course, for a moderator, who may intervene if he or she perceives an unproductive "edit war" to be underway.

Comment: Hmmmm, does the system give me the ability to report an administrator for excessive use of moderator powers? Will i do that if my post will not open? Yeah....

Comment: @JoshPetrie Actually that is not completely right man, u see if u come and make an edit on my post it has to be reviewed, if i make an edit on my post it changed instantly, i think this is the system saying that the OP has more influence on the question than others....

Comment: @JoshPetrie as long as the system gives me the ability/power to do what i want with my post then i do it... its so simple, if i wouldnt be allowed then the system wouldnt let me, simple as dat...

Comment: Having the power to do something doesn't mean you should do it.

Comment: @hedgehog if the user is a moderator, or has over 2000 rep, their edit is applied instantly.

Comment: @Dragonrage so what? you have no point on what you are saying, please rephrase...

Comment: @hedgehog you don't own a question. We don't try to help (just) _you_. We try to help everyone who can have the same issue. We are allowed to edit the question to be more accessible.

Comment: @ardaozkal and i as the OP have the ability to judge if an edit is helpfull for the post or not..... i just answered that on the comments of this question feel free to check it out....

Comment: @hedgehog If you are not good at judging, a mod gets in the way before it escalates and locks the post.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure why you believe that your way of communicating is the sole correct one and that everyone calmly explaining the way our site works is incorrect. StackExchange is not a soapbox for you to yell whatever you want. Our customs have long since been established, and adding extraneous tidbits of text to your questions and answers like "thanks" and signatures are not only discouraged, but actively removed, as you have experienced. This is normal, this is fine, and this is not an insult to you or your ability to write posts. It is minor cleanup, barely worth notice. Everyone here has been more patient with you than you deserve, to be quite honest, for making a big deal out of something so small.

If you do not like our rules, our customs, our precedent, and our user base, you are more than welcome not to use our site. If you do continue to use our site, I expect it to be with a refreshed attitude of trying to learn the way we work rather than trying to enforce your ideals on everyone here.

Comment: The funny thing is that, even if we "didn't" have a "RULE" that said that you "can't" have greetings in your post, well, we now "do", and it's *this very question*. If you expect every little thing to have its own rule, this is not the right website for you, and I wish you best luck on your future endeavours.

Comment: man its so god damn simple.... I am obliged to follow the rules... show me on RULES were it says that and I will accept it.... i repeat, show a RULE not a simple guideline.... @badp still this is a guideline, show it to me on RULES page and I will accept it....

Comment: @hedgehog There is no such thing. We will not have such a thing. We will enforce our simple guidelines. If you expect otherwise, this is not the right website for you, and I wish you best luck on your future endeavours.